# How to keep track of information over several calls to render :partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

I am using attribute_fu to render a nice block of rows for a particular table.

```
<%= f.render_associated_form(@foo.bars, :new => 5) %>
```

I would like to have the `bar` partial have some notion of a bit of state.  (Because the notion is specific to the view, I do not want to externalize this to the `Bar` model itself and calculate it in the controller.)  For simplicity's sake, pretend it is the index of the `bar` in the `@foo.bars` list.

(I am aware that if this was the case I could use the :collection => @foo.bars to enable bar_counter... this doesn't appear to function in my tests but I have seen docs for it.)

My question -- how do I pass a variable into the partial such that I can keep and edit the state?  Naively, I assumed that doing something like

```
<% @tmp = {:index => 1} %>
%= f.render_associated_form(@foo.bars, :new => 5, :locals => {:tmp => @tmp}) %>

#goes in the view
<%= tmp[:index] += 1 %>
```

would work.  `tmp` gets passed appropriately but calling [] throws "Uh oh, you just called a method on nil".  Surprisingly to me, I can do tmp.inspect, tmp.class, etc to look at the Hash, and these have the results I would expect.  But tmp[:index] or tmp[:anything_I_want] cause it to blow up.

Making `tmp` an array had similar results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this in a thoroughly Rails fashion -- patching :attribute_fu to meet my needs.  Hopefully I'll be able to release my patches to the community fairly soon.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe above seems like it must be a bug in attribute_fu, since the local isn't getting properly passed along, which it definitely should.  I'd be interested to know what you did to patch it.